# inconsistent behavior of tikz [fit] and [transform shape]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

I want to frame a set of nodes with the option [fit] ​​and change the overall size of the drawing with [scale = xx, transform shape] but I have unexpected behavior. the frame is no longer valid

the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw](A){A};
\node[right=3em of A,draw](B){B};
\node[left=3em of A,draw](C){C};
\node[above=3em of A,draw](D){D};
\node[below=3em of A,draw](E){E};
\node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E), draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape]
\node[draw](A){A};
\node[right=3em of A,draw](B){B};
\node[left=3em of A,draw](C){C};
\node[above=3em of A,draw](D){D};
\node[below=3em of A,draw](E){E};
\node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E), draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

what can I do?, is this a bug?

Comment: This doesn't happen for me: the entire picture is scaled correctly. What version of PGF/TikZ are you using?

Comment: @Jake I get that via v3

Comment: @percusse: Ha, interesting! I wonder if that's a feature or a regression...

Comment: @Jake That's probably something due to using global switches. I would say this is consistent behavior with undesired result. Scoping as Claudio mentioned in the comment would be the proper way to do it I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to exclude the fitting node to be scaled since it first fits the contents and then applies the scaling to it again. Easiest is to turn off the `transfrom shape` effect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw](A){A};
\node[right=3em of A,draw](B){B};
\node[left=3em of A,draw](C){C};
\node[above=3em of A,draw](D){D};
\node[below=3em of A,draw](E){E};
\node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E), draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
\node[draw](A){A};
\node[right=3em of A,draw](B){B};
\node[left=3em of A,draw](C){C};
\node[above=3em of A,draw](D){D};
\node[below=3em of A,draw](E){E};
\node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D) (E), transform shape=false,draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another way is passing to a `scope` environment the scaling options, include relevant code and leave outside the node used for `fit`ting.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Agreed.

Comment: ok, I'll do that, but it seems to be a regression, I do not remember having this problem with the previous version

Comment: I don't have the problem with the latest version anymore. WIth earlier versions, I add `\tikzset{every fit/.style={transform shape=false}}` to the preamble to solve the problem for all figures.